# Find edges from existing vertices in Spark GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Is there any operation on vertices to get my function to find edges base on some preperties?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Graph.triplets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph):

```
graph.triplets.filter(e => {your_condition})
```